# Если долго смотреть на девушку, то можно увидеть, как она выходит замуж - запятые

Tags: как, пунктуация

Если долго смотреть на девушку, то можно увидеть, как она выходит замуж - нужна ли запятая перед как?

Answer (score 4):

Если долго смотреть на девушку, то можно увидеть, как она выходит замуж.

СПП с неоднородными придаточными условия и изъяснения, стыка союзов нет, запятая ставится.